# (R) Parse character vector and split into two separate columns

Tags: r, regex, parsing, tidyr

I have a dataframe with character columns of mean (sd) like so:

```
table <- tribble(
  ~var1, ~var2,
  #------------
  "27.0 (3.1)", "171.4 (9.0)",
  "27.0 (3.2)", "176.8 (7.2)",
  "27.1 (3.0)", "165.0 (6.2)"
)
```

I would like to split each column into two columns, one for the mean and one for the sd. Something like:

```
table_split <- tribble(
  ~var1_mean, ~var1_sd, ~var2_mean, ~var2_sd,
  #---------------------
  27.0, 3.1, 171.4, 9.0,
  27.0, 3.2, 176.8, 7.2,
  27.1, 3.0, 165.0, 6.2

)
```

So far, I have tried `tidyr::separate(table, var1, c("var1_mean", "var1_sd"), sep = " \\(")` which only partially works as it it does not remove the ending parenthesis.

Comment: `table %>% separate(var1,  c("var1_mean", "var1_sd"), sep = " \\(") %>% mutate(var1_sd = gsub(")", "", var1_sd))`? That is, just add a `mutate` call using `gsub` to remove the final `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `separate` as shown below.  Note that this requires tidyr 0.8.2 or later.  Earlier versions did not support `NA` in the `into` argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  

table %>% 
  separate(var1, into = c("mean1", "sd1", NA), sep = "[ ()]+") %>%
  separate(var2, into = c("mean2", "sd2", NA), sep = "[ ()]+")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  mean1 sd1   mean2 sd2  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 27.0  3.1   171.4 9.0  
2 27.0  3.2   176.8 7.2  
3 27.1  3.0   165.0 6.2
```

Comment: Thank you- this was exactly what I was looking for. If you don't mind, could you explain why sep = "[ ()]+"? I tried sep = "[ ()]" and it did not work. From my understanding, the regex means match one of either space, open or close parenthesis one or more times

Comment: There are two characters between the two numbers so either add the plus as we did so that space-left-paren is regarded as a single separator or else they will be regarded as two separators in which case we would have to use `into = c("mean1", NA, "sd1", NA)`.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you would do:

```
nms = paste0(c('mean','sd'),rep(1:2,each=ncol(table))) # Create the new names

read.table(text=gsub('[()]','',do.call(paste,table)),col.names = nms)

  mean1 sd1 mean2 sd2
1  27.0 3.1 171.4 9.0
2  27.0 3.2 176.8 7.2
3  27.1 3.0 165.0 6.2
```